# Using jQuery, how could I reference the second to last column of a html table row or by class name?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a button inside a td of a html table.  When I click on the button I want to enter certain text into the second to last column of the current row.

I see I can do

```
 td:first
```

or

```
td:nth-child(3)
```

but how can I reference the second to last column of the current table?

```
 <table> 
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type='button' class="myButton"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

alternatively, I could put a class name on the column td if that makes it easier to reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [nth-last-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/)

```
$(currentrow).find( "td:nth-last-child(2)" ).append( content );
```

Ex:

```
$('.myButton').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-last-child(2)').text('asdf')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yNc2B/)

If you want to target the previous cell of the button then

```
$('.myButton').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().prev().text('asdf')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BQjdX/)